# Unable to find Element even after using webdriverwait and switch to options

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a website I need to scrape. I am not able to use the find_element option using selenium in order to fill in the search term. I have tried using webdriverwait and solution for iframe using switch to option but these do not work.

the link is 'https://www.notredame.edu.au/staff/staff-directory'
I am using selenium can I also use requests module? I am not sure. I have also tried using xpath, id and name as well.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\albert.malhotra\\Desktop\\Web Scrapings\\Kentucky State\\chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.notredame.edu.au/staff/staff-directory'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tbSimpleSearchName")))
```

I should be able to use send_keys method to enter the search criteria and scrape data from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to achieve the required result. Make sure to replace `something` with any valid search keyword.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL = "https://www.notredame.edu.au/staff/staff-directory"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(URL)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[name='Staff Directory']")))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tbSimpleSearchName"))).send_keys("something",Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind helping me with clicking the next button? I tried browser.find_element but it throws an error of 'InvalidSelectorException'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to wait for an element inside of an IFrame.

You need to wait for the IFrame itself, switch to it, and then you can select the element inside of the IFrame.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.Name,"Staff Directory")))
```

(I haven't tested the above code, and I don't think `By.Name` is the right selector, but hopefully that gives you the idea.

Comment: I have used the similar code:-    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tbSimpleSearchName")))

Comment: Right:  The `tbSimpleSearchName` is the problem here:  It is an element *within* an IFrame.  You cannot wait for it.  You have to wait for the IFrame itself.